# Why Protege makes a copy of DatatypeProperty as ObjectProperty

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api

I noticed that Protege creates "copies" properties I created as DatatypeProperty and marks them as  ObjectProperty. Which in turn makes them to be both datatype and object property at the same time. 
I tried to fix it manually in the OWL file.
Assigned "xsd:string" as Range.
Nothing helps.

Protege reads in the OWL file and shows the property I just fixed on both lists. If I modify anything and it will save the ontology back to the OWL file, two entries will be made.

What is more "funny" my Range specification (to xsd:string) is set to the ObjectProperty entry, not the original Datatype.

Any ideas?

Here is an example.

"Original"

```
###  http://www.umwd.dolnyslask.pl/ontologies/2014/03/midas#title

:title rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ,
               owl:FunctionalProperty ;

      rdfs:label "tytuł"@pl ;

      skos:definition """xxxxxx""" ;

      rdfs:comment """comment"""@pl ;

      rdfs:domain :Annotation ,
                  :Entity .
```

Copy added by Protege (notice that rdfs:range has been moved to the copy)

```
###  http://www.umwd.dolnyslask.pl/ontologies/2014/03/midas#title

:title rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;

       rdfs:label "tytuł"@pl ;

       skos:definition """xxxxxx""" ;

       rdfs:comment """comment"""@pl ;

       rdfs:range xsd:string .
```

**UPDATE**: Here is the minimal ontology which after opening in protege results in problem shown above:

```
@prefix : <http://my.ontolo.gy/test#> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix midas: <http://my.ontolo.gy/test#> .
@prefix vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> .
@prefix dctype: <http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.rdfs.org/all#> .
@prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix location: <http://www.w3.org/ns/locn#> .
@base <http://my.ontolo.gy/test> .

<http://my.ontolo.gy/test> rdf:type owl:Ontology ;
                         rdfs:label "Ontologia"@pl ;
                         rdfs:comment "Komentarz"@pl ;
                         owl:imports bibo: ,
                                     <http://schema.rdfs.org/all> ,
                                     <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns> ,
                                     <http://www.w3.org/ns/locn> .

###  http://my.ontolo.gy/test#title

:title rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ,
             owl:FunctionalProperty ;
    rdfs:label "tytuł"@pl ;
    skos:definition """definition""" ;
    rdfs:comment """komentarz"""@pl ;
    rdfs:range xsd:string ;
    rdfs:domain :Annotation ,
                :Entity .
```

And after saving it back to the file:

```
@prefix : <http://my.ontolo.gy/test#> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix midas: <http://my.ontolo.gy/test#> .
@prefix vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#> .
@prefix dctype: <http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.rdfs.org/all#> .
@prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix location: <http://www.w3.org/ns/locn#> .
@base <http://my.ontolo.gy/test> .

<http://my.ontolo.gy/test> rdf:type owl:Ontology ;

                           rdfs:label "Ontologia"@pl ;

                           rdfs:comment "Komentarz"@pl ;

                           owl:imports bibo: ,
                                       <http://schema.rdfs.org/all> ,
                                       <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns> ,
                                       <http://www.w3.org/ns/locn> .


#################################################################
#
#    Object Properties
#
#################################################################


###  http://my.ontolo.gy/test#title

:title rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;

       rdfs:label "tytuł "@pl ;

       skos:definition "definition" ;

       rdfs:comment "komentarz"@pl ;

       rdfs:range xsd:string .





#################################################################
#
#    Data properties
#
#################################################################


###  http://my.ontolo.gy/test#title

:title rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ,
                owl:FunctionalProperty ;

       rdfs:label "tytuł "@pl ;

       skos:definition "definition" ;

       rdfs:comment "komentarz"@pl ;

       rdfs:domain :Annotation ,
                   :Entity .





#################################################################
#
#    Classes
#
#################################################################


###  http://my.ontolo.gy/test#Annotation

:Annotation rdf:type owl:Class .



###  http://my.ontolo.gy/test#Entity

:Entity rdf:type owl:Class .




###  Generated by the OWL API (version 3.4.2) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net
```

Comment: Is there any use of the `title` property where it relates an individual to another individual.  Protege might see that and, because only object prpoerties can do that, add an object property declaration for the property.  Even so, it definitely shouldn't be the case that the range of an object property is `xsd:string`.  Can you reproduce this with a minimal example?  I.e., show us an ontology that has just one property, but when opened and saved by Protege has two?

Comment: I've added the most simple ontology example I could think of - it is just this one property with all imports. There are of course other `title` properties (e.g., in DC) but they have different URIs.

Comment: Are the imports required?  E.g., do you get the same behavior if there are no imports?

Comment: When imports are removed it all works fine. My ontology references concepts from those imported ontologies. I would try to avoid doing all referencing manually. I can as well start editing this ontology outside Protege completely :/

Comment: hm, in the minimal example, only one that seems to be used is SKOS.  Do you get the same results if you don't import SKOS?

Comment: I have removed SKOS, and in a second run SKOS & DC. In both cases - object property is created

Comment: I still see SKOS in the "minimal" example in the question.  Can you update it?  (By the way, I suspect that this is probably some sort of bug in Protege/OWLAPI, or something that's tucked away in one of the imports.  If it's a bug, there isn't much we can do about it, but at least we'll have a good example to file a bug report with, right?

Comment: Sorry, tested on my machine, forgot to update the example.

Comment: Where do I file bug request for Protege?

Comment: I'm actually not able to load your latest ontology into Protege;  things just seem to hang.  Maybe we're using different versions.  The most common place to ask, I think, is on the Protege users list that you can join from http://protege.stanford.edu/support.php.

Comment: I am using Protege 4.3.0 (build 304)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause for this is that, during parsing, (by the OWL API)

`rdfs:range xsd:string`

is considered to be asserting that the range is the `xsd:string` /class/. This is clearly a problem. I've seen it before when ontologies contain erroneous declarations of `xsd:string` as a class, which is a violation of the OWL 2DL profile.

The origin of this appears to be in the schema.rdfs.org/all import, where this kind of construct can be found:

`rdfs:range [ a owl:Class; owl:unionOf (xsd:decimal xsd:string) ];`

In order for this to parse, the datatype IRIs need to be coopted to be class IRIs. This is the first OWL profile violation, and the other violations are caused by its side effects.

The schema ontology appears to be RDF rather than OWL, so I'm not sure if it makes sense to try and fix these issues.

Comment: Thanks for this analysis. I check what happens if I remove schema.rdfs.org/all import and this problem is still there. Btw I imported the ontology into Webprotege and this problem did not show up there.

Comment: I haven't checked all ontologies, so the same problem might originate from other axioms. One thing that Protege might be doing and WebProtege might not be doing is adding declarations when saving the ontology. This would cause the violations to be embedded as multiple declarations. I'll open an issue with the OWL API to not add declarations that cause violations.